# Migrate harddisk with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, migration

A few years ago I got a laptop, this had a internal disk with windows 10.
When I got it I inserted a second harddrive. And I made a dual boot and installed Ubuntu only on that second disk.

Now I got a new Laptop, and I want the same setup, the default harddrive windows 10, and dual boot ubuntu on my second disk.

Can I do this without reinstalling Ubuntu, and formatting that second disk?
I guess you would need to update the grub and stuff like that.

Can someone help me get started with this?

The current disks layout
[image: Current laptop setup]

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely!** - But be careful!!

It depends on a couple of things, though.

You may be able to tell your BIOS that the second disk is the primary boot disk.  Have you tried that?

If that doesn't work, then you'll need to reinstall the bootloader somewhere.  That can be:

1. On the primary hard drive boot sector; or
2. On the secondary drive boot sector (and use the Windows Boot Manager); or
3. On the secondary drive boot partition; or
4. Any combination of the above

The overall process is to:

1. Gain access to the drive either by booting Ubuntu off a USB key
2. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file to specify the correct partition (UUIDs can be helpful here to avoid writing to the wrong device.)
3. `chroot` into the partition and run `update-grub`

There may be easier options by using "Rescue a broken system" on the USB key, but I haven't tried those.

There's also a [handy tutorial here](https://www.tecmint.com/rescue-repair-and-reinstall-grub-boot-loader-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
I've added a screenshot pf my current layout. I think I've created the boot partition on the windows disk.

Comment: The boot sector and boot partition are separate things.  You can't see the boot sector because it's the first 512k of each disk.  You need the boot sector to "jump" to one of the boot managers.  Then the boot manager will "chainload" the OS. Grub installs its bootloader into the boot sector and then calls the boot partition.  Windows does the same thing.  Both can chainload the other.  So it's up to you which boot manager you wish to use.

Comment: Okay, I'll check these things in the weekend, including that guide (looks promising)